# Is there a way to declare Status and Level in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I usually use SQL Server so declare variables in Oracle seem different a little.

Here is the table Im trying to create:

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EmpNo char(10) CONSTRAINT PK_EmpNo PRIMARY KEY,
EmpName varchar2(30),
Birthday DATE not null,
DeptNo number,
MgrNo varchar2(30) not null,
StartDate DATE not null,
Salary number(7,2) not null,
Level number CONSTRAINT Level_ck check (Level > 0 AND Level < 8) not null,
Status number CONSTRAINT Status_ck check (Status >= 0 AND Status <= 2) not null,
Note varchar2(4000));
```

This is the error:

[image]

I think I declare Level and Status wrong because when I remove them out of the Table, the table can be created.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEVEL` is a reserved word that cannot be used as an identifier. Every database has them; the complete list of reserved words for Oracle is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612

`STATUS` is not a reserved word, and you should be able to create a column with that name.

Also note that table and column names in Oracle are not case-sensitive by default, so using camelCase isn't really appropriate (it will only be visible in your `CREATE TABLE` DDL command). A more standard naming convention is to use underscores to separate components of a label, such as `START_DATE` or `DEPT_NR` or `TABLE_A`.

Comment: So what should I declare with the level variable? Also, the Status work fine with the variable i have declared, tks.

Comment: Just rename the column, Anna. Instead of LEVEL, use e.g. C_LEVEL.

Comment: I have done it, tks guys.